# boost armv7 build

Tags: iphone, boost, armv7

I tried this to build armv7 boost libs:

```
./bjam toolset=darwin cflags="-fvisibility=default" architecture=arm target-os=iphone macosx-version=iphone-4.1 link=static threading=multi define=_LITTLE_ENDIAN include=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv7-apple-darwin10 --with-thread --with-date_time
```

But the lipo -info command told me that the compiled library is armv6, not armv7 lib!

Could anyone please tell me a boost command line to create a libs with armv7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the "-arch armv7" flag to the compiler. In your example, setting architecture=armv7 should probably do the trick.

In any case, armv6 executables can always be run (to the extent of my knowledge) on armv7 CPUs.

Comment: Thank you! I added this to the user-config.jam :\nusing darwin : 4.2.1~iphone
   : /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
   : <striper>
     <compileflags>"-arch armv7"
     <compileflags>-mthumb
     <compileflags>-fvisibility=hidden
     <compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
     <compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
   : <architecture>arm <target-os>iphone
   ;\n and extract armv6 part from the resulting binaries - so the true armv7 libs has been produced!